# Surface Lit on Wrong Side (UE 5.3)

Tags: rendering, lighting, unreal, normals

I have a triangular mesh and a directional light in UE 5.3.2. The directional light is facing in +Z direction (up). Can anyone explain to me why the top surface is lit instead of being in a shadow (i.e. black)?

[image]

I would have thought that if the directional light was facing in the -Z direction (down) the top surface would be lit (like above), but it's completely dark:

[image]

Looking at Blender, it appears the triangle normals are all facing in the +Z direction.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: All meshes have a "Cast Shadow" setting located in the Lighting section. Do you have it enabled?

Comment: Good question. Both the directional light and mesh have "Cast Shadow" enabled.

Comment: Then I don't know but I would add a regular plane to see if the lighting works fine with it. If it does, it means the issue is in your statis mesh. I don't know much about Blender but I believe there are several ways of exporting meshes, I would test different export methods. Also, for science, even if the normals are in the Z direction, try reversing and exporting again to Unreal to see what happens. A bit of trial and error and perhaps you might solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting advice. I exported the plane from a UE project I downloaded to see what it looked like in Blender. I then re-exported it in Blender and imported into UE with the same result. If I make a plane in Blender from scratch (where the normals look as above), import it into UE, the light shows on the correct side.